# Is there a way to make the same URL page refresh if they're on the same server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was wondering if there's a method to force a URL page to refresh on command using JS that's on the same server.

Ex: I have a URL page that's open on three devices on the same server. When I click update, the URL will automatically refresh on all three devices?

I can only figure out how to fresh it if it's on the same device right now.

CODE IN MY PHP FILE:

```html
   function refresh() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    location.reload(true)
    }, 100);
  }
```

CODE IN MY HTML:

```html
button onclick="updateData(); refresh()">Update</button>
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. The server must push a command to all devices to reload the page. This is usually done using websockets.

Comment: you must use websockets or sse ( Server-Sent Events ) to push command to all users in your website

Comment: websockets is best for live data but if you cannot use websockets for whatever reason then I guess you could use ajax to call a server-side page to check for update but this will mean you have to make a record of the last thing loaded for the client to compare with the existing/new content. This wouldn't be an instant update either, this would be done using an interval and would make many useless calls so websockets would be very beneficial if you insist on live data. Also I would reload the full page, I would just display the new data.

Answer (score 0):

You should set ajax data retrieve task on every set seconds.(loop script)
If Ajax script found there is your command to reload, take the task.

Eg:get data from reload.txt 
do nothing on get value is 0, And your action make the txt to 1.
If ajax script found it is 1, do reload by the script.

1 - Create reload.txt beside your page.php and write only 0 in txt.
In your php file write this script inside html part -

```
<script>
function load(){
 $.ajax({
        url : "reload.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            if (data == 0) {
            $(".text").html(data); // to check number and not necessary for your function
            }
            else{
                window.top.location = "/";
                <?php $file = fopen("reload.txt","w");
                fwrite($file,"0");
                fclose($file); ?>
            }
        }
});
}

load(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
load() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000); 

</script>   

<div class="text">will appear here</div> // to check number and not necessary for your function
```

For complete function you need to set it 0 on page reload.
And Finally add function to change txt value to be 1 in your server reload button and test it.

PS: You should innovate your function than 0/1 method. just like incremental or something and store it in $_SESSION to work for all of clients.

Comment: Could you show me an example? I'm not familiar with this

Comment: I edited the answer and make sure your txt file has full permission to read/write. Good luck .

Comment: is there a way to have the page load only if the user decides?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your meaning. "if the user decides", do you wanna meant to what ? Because as far as I know, user decide reload can be done in many ways by their actions.